# TypeScript question about type intersection and extends behaviour

Tags: typescript

I am confused about the following behaviour:

```js
type A = [1, 2, 3];
type B = A extends [infer H, ...infer T] ? [...T, H] : never;

type C = [1, 2, 3] & any[];
type D = C extends [infer H, ...infer T] ? [...T, H] : never;
```

In the top case, we have `type B = [2, 3, 1]`, but in the bottom case, we have `type D = [...unknown[], any]`. Why is that, and how can I "prevent" that i.e. match the array only?

(I am beginner at TypeScript, sorry if this is covered somewhere :) )

---

**Edit:** Here is a more realistic example:

```js
type Nums = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;
type ArrayOfNumbers = Nums[];
type Data = {
  arr: ArrayOfNumbers,
  aux: number
};

type ReverseArr<Arr extends any[], Acc extends any[] = []> =
  Arr extends [infer H, ...infer T] ? ReverseArr<T, [H, ...Acc]> : Acc;

// I want to specify ReverseData<D> is of type Data
type ReverseData<D extends Data> = {
  arr: ReverseArr<D["arr"]> & ArrayOfNumbers,
  aux: D["aux"]
};

type ActualData = { arr: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], aux: 2 };
type ok = ReverseData<ActualData>; // { arr: [4, 3, 2, 1, 0] & ArrayOfNumbers, aux: 2 }
type not_ok = ReverseData<ok>;     // { arr: [0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4] & ArrayOfNumbers, aux: 2 }
```

Or is this quite unconventional use case of types?

Comment: Intersections of arrays are weird and not recommended (see [ms/TS#41874](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41874)). I don't know I have a great answer for "why" this is matching in the particular way (I think one would need to step thru the compiler code to know what).  When you say "match the array only" do you mean the *tuple*? (both `[1,2,3]` and `any[]` are array types). If so, I'm not sure it's possible, at least not easily. What's the use case? Why are you starting with something unpleasant like an intersection of arrays? Maybe we can fix the problem before you get there.

Comment: (see prev comment).  Like, I could try to perform risky surgery on `C` to get something without the `any[]`, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3qnyw), but this is really suboptimal compared to just avoiding that intersection in the first place.  I'm happy to turn this into an answer but I do wonder if we can back up to the use case so we can be sure this isn't an XY problem.

Comment: @jcalz For context, I'm messing with type-level computation (for [Advent of TypeScript](https://typehero.dev/challenge/day-21), if you have heard of that), so maybe this is unconventional and I should just avoid it. I have updated the post with a minimal example of what I want to do that *might* be closer to an IRL example.

Comment: This is most definitely not a common use case (you usually try to functions / variables, not other conditional types?), so it might just be that "array intersections are weird", as you mentioned. If so, feel free to put it as an answer and I can accept it. I was just wondering while messing around :D